# In Ember.js, how can I ensure that controllers for multiple templates rendered via {{render}} keep their own association with their parent controller?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

[Here's a JS Fiddle of what I'm talking about](http://jsfiddle.net/Kerrick/eVgZB/).

I am rendering three `Item`s on screen via the `{{render}}` helper, each of which shows the `Item`'s `Subitem`s. (I can't just use outlets, as multiple expanded items must be visible at the same time).

`Subitems` is properly initialized with their own unique instances of the `SubitemsController`. However, in the `subitems` template and controller, the `controllers.item` references **whatever `Item` was opened last**.

This is bad, because if I were to put a Create Subitem form inside of the `subitems` template and associate it as a child of the `Item`, it will associate the new `Subitem` with the most recently opened `Item`, instead of the `Item` the form is actually in.

How can I work around this and ensure I can access the proper `Item` from the `SubitemsController` and/or `subitems` template?

Answer (score 0):

`render` is intended to render a single view/controller pair for things like global nav, search, etc. You probably want `view` or `partial`.

Comment: According to [the Ember Documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper), `{{render}}` seems to be exactly what I need here -- a template powered by an instance of a given Controller, visible multiple times on a page.

`{{partial}}` doesn't change context, which is no good, and `{{view}}` doesn't give me a Controller, which won't work if I need to, say, create a new `Subitem`.

The only problem with `{{render}}` is that the Controller that each `needs` (via `needs: ['item']`) stays in sync between the unique Controllers.